# Retaining table view cell's text field data

Tags: objective-c

How to retain table cell's text field data entered by the user after user scroll the table view or comes back the to table after navigating to another view?

i'm working on an iPhone app which has a table containing labels and text fields in its cells
. after filling the text fields whenever i scroll the dat in the text fields comes to blank.
plz help me .

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow MVC: keep the underlying model data separately from it's view representation.

If your data is a string per table row, then create an `NSMutableArray` to hold the `NSString`s returned from your `UITextField.text` values.

Expanding to fill in some basic details: `UITableViewCell`s can be reused for efficiency.  That's what the docs say.  Which means that, as soon as a cell is no longer visible, it is a candidate for reuse.  The `UITableView` structure is a view layer component; the strings that you keep in it are your "model".  They should be maintained separately.

So, rather than attempting to store your strings in the table cells, which is a bad idea AND won't work, construct an array of strings that you can display in the `UITextField` that you have added to the cells.  A dictionary is an alternative data structure to hold your strings, but if you are following the linear nature of a table view, it seems unlikely that using a dictionary keyed with your row indexes will have any advantage over an array.

Comment: thanks Paul but it's a tableview cell........plz see my detailed question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860883/text-in-uitableviecell-missing-when-scroll-down

Answer (score 0):

Take Dictionary and save values of the textfields with key values as indexpaths , 
in cellforrow delegate method, display textfield data retrieving from the dictionary.

In textfileddidendediting delegate method, save the value of textfield to the dictionary.

Or else you can use array also to save values.